# Most efficient way to test whether each element from one 1-d array exists in corresponding row of another 2-d array, using python

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to know the most efficient way to test whether each element from one 1-d array exists in corresponding row of another 2-d array, using python

Specifically, I have two arrays. The first is an 1-d array of integers. The second is a 2-d array of integers.

Sample input:

```
[1, 4, 12, 9] # array 1

[[1, 12, 299],
 [2, 5, 11],
 [1, 3, 11],
 [0, 1, 9]] # array 2
```

Expected output:

```
[True, False, False, True]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reshape `a` to 2d array, compare with `b` and then check if there's any `True` in each row:

```
np.equal(np.reshape(a, (-1,1)), b).any(axis=1)
```

---

```
a = [1, 4, 12, 9] # array 1
​
b = [[1, 12, 299],
     [2, 5, 11],
     [1, 3, 11],
     [0, 1, 9]] 

np.equal(np.reshape(a, (-1,1)), b).any(1)
# array([ True, False, False,  True], dtype=bool)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a fairly pythonic solution to your problem. Note that this works virtually identically for numpy arrays and standard lists. Definitely not the most efficient solution for huge numpy arrays, but I doubt this would be any type of performance bottleneck, and pursuing premature optimization over readability is a cardinal sin.

```
a = [1, 4, 12, 9]
b = [
    [1, 12, 299],
    [2, 5, 11],
    [1, 3, 11],
    [0, 1, 9]
    ]

c = [x in y for x, y in zip(a,b)]
```